# Posterior distribution, a multivitamin example

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

A company sells multivitamin tablets, claiming that they reduce the probability of getting a cold by 90%. To evaluate the true efficacy of the the tablets, a clinical-trials organisation tests the tablets in n
 healthy volunteers.

For each volunteer, let α
 denote the probability of getting a cold while on a course of the tablets, and let $β$
 denote the probability of getting a cold while not on a course of the tablets. Suppose
$$α=(1−a)β,$$
where a
 denotes the efficacy of the tablets, $0≤a≤1$
. If the tablets are as effective as the company claims, then $a=0.9$
.

Suppose, before the trial beings, you believe the efficacy $a$
 of the tablets lies with Uniform probability anywhere between 0 and 0.9. Suppose each of the $n$
 volunteers catches a cold during the trial, independently of all others. Derive your posterior pdf for $a$
 as a function of the number of volunteers, n
.

For the case of $n=10$
, evaluate your posterior pdf for $a$
 for each value of $a∈{\{0,0.1,0.2,…,1\}}$
, entering your answers to 3 decimal places.

Could you please steer me in the right direction, my whole class is lost and so am I. This has to do with posterior distribution.